# How do I hardcode a route root for Url.Action when generating a confirmation link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Asp.net core web app can generate a confirmation link successfully using

```
string confirmationLink = Url.Action("SetPassword","Account", 
                          new
                          {
                              userid = userMaster.Id,
                              token = confirmationToken
                          },
protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
```

This roots the route using the root of the current controller's page.

Now I have moved out the logic to a web api and I would like to use the root of the calling page in the Url.Action statement in the webapi.

I want to achieve following points.

**a)** get the root of the current page and

**b)** having passed that root to the `webApi` how do I seed `Url` with it so that it is available to `Url.Action`?

**Workaround:** I am generating the confirmation link as a simple string.

```
string confirmationLink =           ${this.config.p_ConfirmationURLRoot}/{this.config.p_ConfirmatonURLController}/{this.config.p_ConfirmationURLAction}?userId={ userMaster.Id}&token={ confirmationToken}";
```

This does not resolve the questions posed above, but if like me your end goal is a working link that may be used else where, this approach will satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to work with request-routing for a front-end application using the routing of a separate API. This isn't a use-case for the ASP.NET routing systems; they are only interested in routes within the application domain. The front-end application has its routes and the API has its routes: both are completely separate concerns.

This is a good model, one you want to work with rather than against. The front-end application should be free to change its URLs without requiring changes in other applications.

By all means, have a separate API to perform logic like user-creation and validation of security tokens, but these are not concerns which should be intermingled with front-end routing.